# Find out the rate of change of rise of water at that moment.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

The height and radius of a circular cone are $6\,\mathrm m$ and $8\,\mathrm m$ respectively. Water is pouring  at a constant rate of $4\pi\,\mathrm{cm}^3/\mathrm s$ from another jar.  Find out the rate of change of rise of water column inside the cone,when the radius of water column is $4\,\mathrm m\,$.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to include what you have done so far on this problem.

Comment: In what sense is the question related to differential geometry?

Comment: Hint: Use similar triangles along the way.

Answer (score 1):

let volume=$V$ and height $h$
if the angle at the base of the triangular crosssection of the cone be $\theta$ then $\tan\theta=\frac{6}{8}$, $r=\frac{h}{\tan\theta}=\frac{4h}{3}$
in the question you are given $\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi$. you have to find the value of $\frac{dh}{dt}$.
$$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\pi \frac{d}{dt}\frac{16}{9}h^3$$
 $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\pi \frac{16}{9}3h^2\frac{dh}{dt}$$
further $\frac{16}{9}h^2=r^2$
substitute for $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and find $\frac{dh}{dt}$